# How to make a theme'd table that is sortable and has pager?

Tags: paging, theming

So I get an array from another function and now I need to style it into a table and make the headers sortable and have a pager on it.

I've been able to do this when querying the database directly but when receiving the info in an array from an external API I'm unsure of how to do this.

http://alvinalexander.com/drupal/drupal-7-table-sortable-headers-pager-paging

Has an example of how I've done it in the past but cannot do it this way this time.

Is it possible to do this without completely rewriting my own theme table function?